# How to handle custom exceptions in Spring Aspect class?

Tags: java, spring-boot, exception, spring-aop, aspect

I need to know how can i handle custom exceptions in my Aspect class, so that i can print log out of it?
Below is my Aspect class:

```
@Around("@annotation(com.aspect.LoggableService)")
    public Object ServiceMetrices(ProceedingJoinPoint pjp) throws Throwable {
        try {
            pjp.proceed();
        } catch(CustomException ex) {
            // logging exception details here 
            LOGGER.info("Logs for API Metrices " + pjp.getSignature() + " {} " + 
            return pjp.proceed();

    } catch (Exception ex) {
            // Logging exception details

            LOGGER.info("Logs for API Metrices " + pjp.getSignature() + " {} " + 
            return pjp.proceed();
        }
```

I am calling this aspect annotation after the execution from my service class.

```
try {
            //Code
        }
        catch(HttpClientErrorException x) {
            throw new CustomException(x.getStatusCode(),"POST Request failed");
        }
```

I want my exceptions to be handled by my CustomException block in my Aspect class instead of handling it in Exception class.

Comment: Your aspect code calls the target one more time when the exception happens, which ideally should result in another exception.  Return null on exception and I think that should resolve the issue

Comment: Did the suggestion solve the issue for you ? If not , could you please explain what is the exact requirement and what is not working now ?